# Angularjs route doesn't show html in view source, but react does

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

As I'm using angular `route` for my SPA, my *view page source* is empty (only ng-view exists). I see a website developed by `react` , has the similar functionality. But when I see the page source, content is there. (ex for [angular](http://vahidnajafi.ir), ex for [react](http://evand.com))

How is it possible in react ? And why not in angular? Any idea?

**Edit:** As crawlers like google, supports SPA crawling since a few years ago, Is it really necessary to use server side rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server side rendering might not be implemented in angular project which you are looking at, that's why you are not able to see the rendered html. React and angular2 has the feature of server side rendering, which means you can render html from your script on server and send that html to client.

Comment: It is always better to do server side rendering, even if some search engine  says that it executes your script for SEO. Page speed, time to first paint, User experience, rendering in javascript disabled environment, and also SEO, all these things matters very much according to me. All these things are easy to integrate and have good outcome when we use server-side rendering using any frameworks or library.

Comment: Thanks. And how about `XMLHttpRequest` ? As data is fetching by ajax request, how does server side handle this? Any idea or approach?

Comment: You can fetch that too on server and pass fetched data to your components and the components will render html with the given data. I have used this technique by following this boilerplate of reactjs https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo

Answer (score 2):

You can see only in page sources ng-views because it doesn't execute JS what is needed to render another elements in your SPA. React can be rendered on server side and gives rendered HTML to your browser while Angular is rendered only in your browser

Comment: Thanks. But it seems that is a javascript independent issue.